# Cannot add android support library to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Please, I'm having this error whenever I try to add `com.android.support:support-v426.0.0-alpha1`. The error is given below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>    Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is Android studio detected 2 different versions of Android support library. The case here would be the support library version 25.3.1 in another library that you are importing.

I would suggest you don't use the alpha version (26-alpha) and change it to version 25.3.1

Comment: I cannot find version 25.3.1 on the list of library dependency

Comment: Can you post all the library dependencies?

Comment: com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:leanback-v17:26.0.0-alpha1
com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1

Comment: One of the libraries that you are using is dependant on support library 25.3.1 (you can't view it until you use the dependency analyzer or wait till Android studio throws the error) although they all are version 26.0.0 alpha. So yeah, use the version 25.3.1 for the build.

Answer (score 1):

There must be another library importing 25.3.1, there is no other way.
It might be a thirdparty library you are importing. Find the library which is depending on that 25.3.1 support lib. You can exclude it with

```
compile ('library........'){
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v7'
}
```